# How do I pass data from app.post to app.get on different pages?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In my app.js file, I am trying to pass the username from a form on the login page to the game page. I've got the data in `req.body.username` in `app.post('/login')`, but how should I pass this to `app.get('/game')`?

I considered making a global variable outside of the functions and then changing this in `app.post('/login')`, but that doesn't seem like a good way of doing things.

```js
// Login
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/login');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username)
});

// Game
app.get('/game/:name', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/game', {
        user: req.params.name
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is what my form looks like (`login.ejs`):

```html
<main class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Login Page</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post">
      <p>Name:</p>
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</main>
```

I'd also like the form to send the user to the game page when it's submitted. I tried changing `action="#"` to `action="game"`, but that gave me an error  - `Cannot POST /game`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could redirect to the game page with the username appended. ``res.redirect(`/game/${req.body.username}`);``. And the `action` attribute value on the form should be `/login` to post your form to the login endpoint.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks, changing the `action` attribute worked. However, I'd like to change `app.get('/game/:name'` to `app.get('/game/'`, so you can't see the username in the URL. I assume this would make the redirect not work as intended, so is there another way?

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess that you would accomplish that by setting a cookie which holds the username. The `/game` endpoint would then have to read the cookie to see who is logged in and render the template based on the username in the cookie.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to look into that then. Never used cookies with Node.js, although I do have a rudimentary understanding of how they work in Flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how one might do this. You'll need the [cookie-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) package to read out the cookie from the request headers.

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

When a user hits the `/login` page, you'll want to set a cookie based on the user name. The name of the cookie could be anything you want. After setting the cookie, redirect to the `/game` endpoint.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('current-user', req.body.username);
  res.redirect('/game');
});
```

Now we have a cookie stored with the data from the `/login` page, we can read it on any other endpoint. Because of the cookie-parser middleware we should now have access to `req.cookie`, which holds an object with all the cookie key-values pairs. Check if the cookie we just set exists and render the page with the user passed to the `render` function.

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  const currentUser = cookies['current-user'];

  if (currentUser) {
    res.render('pages/game', {
      user: currentUser
    });
  } else {
    res.render('pages/game');
  }
});
```